# How do I ensure that a VPS host will keep my information private?

Tags: vpn, confidentiality

Basically, I want to use OpenVPN on a VPS to browse confidentially. However, I don't know much about VPS hosters and to me, it seems to be a hard choice because there are so many.

However, I think it's important to choose the right one because it seems to be pointless to set up your own VPN if the VPS hoster is willing to share your personal information with anybody (I assume I would have to enter my name and that kind of information when I'll sign up for the server).

How do I know if I can trust the VPS hoster to keep my personal information for itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you cannot. You want to use a VPS for your browsing because you fear that some unnamed but powerful evil people would spy on you. How can you know that any given private business, that you don't know beforehand, is not in league with your enemies ? And if I did point you to a specific hosting service, saying "these one are good", how would you know that *I* am not in league with your enemies ? After all, from your point of view, I am just an anonymous user with a bear avatar...

You might want to research [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/): that's like using a randomly chosen chain of VPS. It will protect your privacy, to a large extent, as long as at least one of them is not subverted by your enemies.

Comment: You made me even more paranoid now, god damn bears. I'll look into it. Really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Legal documents.

More specifically, the Terms & Conditions you agreed to when renting a VPS from a provider.

Comment: That is indeed a great idea to know what they allow themselves to do with your information, thanks!